# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

DevOps's [first moderator election](https://devops.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Pierre.Vriens] [image: 030]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Dave Swersky and Tensibai who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5174648553603072/0).

Comment: Congrats and welcome to the squad pierre.vriens and 030. Godspeed! :)

Comment: Thanks for the kudos, happy to be elected! But, why does the *Moderator Agreement* requires me to accept the privacy policy of SO.SE, instead of the one from DevOps.SE (that's what the hyperlink points to)? Can this link be fixed please?

Answer (score 10):

Congrats you both :)

You'll have more l'attitude to continue the good work you've been doing on moderating this site.

Take some time to get accustomed to the TL, the place is a bit shaking lately but you'll always find good advices there.

Comment: I can't stress enough how important your leadership is/was to the community. Thanks for everything Tensibai. Hope you stay around and stay active on the site :)

Comment: ***Merci Patron*** (I trust that those who know some French will understand the real meaning of what that means)! It'll be tough to ever come close to what you did for DevOps.SE up till now...